# Enforce GetLatest on file read

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops, getlatest

Is it possible to force the user to get latest of a file before reading from it?

An example would be for our custom Code Analysis rule set (`.ruleset`).  I do not want someone to run Code Analysis on an old version of the rule set.

We are using  Visual Studio Online and Visual Studio 2013 and Team Foundation Version Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in Visual Studio for this, and it doesn't really make sense to always want to enforce this for all files in a workspace, sometimes you *need* to build against an older version of the code. That said, you could add a pre-build action that uses the TFS commandline to get the latest version of these specific files, something like:

```
>TF get $/Project/CodeAnalysisRules/MyProject.Ruleset /version:T
```

You [might need to disable the `UseHostCompilerIfAvailable`](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/06/just-in-time-updating-of-source-files.html) flag in your project file, as it [might otherwise not detect the changed file till after the build has completed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485062/736079).

Comment: I think a better approach would be leaving the Code Analysis checks to the automatic CI build.

Comment: Agreed, Using a CI build would be ideal, though if you build a specific Changeset or Label it will still not use the latest version of the `.ruleset` file. If Build is not available, this is the "next best thing" if you have such a requirement.